# post array from checkboxes is always returning empty

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

i am trying to delete the email entries from check boxes in a form , but it is unable to fetch any value from `'todelete[]'` array

here is the code:

```
<?php
     $dbc= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customer_base')or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    $query = "select * from email_list";
    $result= mysqli_query($dbc, $query)or die('Error querying database.');

        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' .$row['id']. '"name="todelete[]" />';
       echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'].' '.$row['email'].' '.'<br />';
    }

        if((isset($_POST['submit']))&&(isset($_POST['todelete']))){
        $output_form= false;
        foreach($_POST['todelete'] as $delete_id){
           $query = "delete from email_list where id = $delete_id";
           mysqli_query($dbc,$query)or die('Error querying database.');
        }
        echo '<p>Customer entry removed</p>'.'<br />';
    }elseif((isset($_POST['submit']))&&(empty($_POST['todelete']))){
           echo "<p>you haven't selected any customer entry to delete!</p>";
           $output_form= true;
       }else {$output_form= true; }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    if($output_form){
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="remove" />
    </form>
<?php
   }

?>
```

now,if no checkbox is checked, it gives the message , to select the checkboxes, but even if the checkboxes are selected , it still returns the message to select the checkboxes.
So, it is never enters the loop for delete query , aka`$_POST['todelete']` is always empty, but it should not. u tried to check whether the `$_POST` array is empty , it didn;t comeup with any thing ,
i tried to go through a lot of answers ,but it seems my query was unresolved... Need help !!

What am i doing wrong with the code ??

Comment: Your checkboxes are out of your `<form>` code.

Comment: Thanks @ShankarDamodaran  , i ought to have checked my code structure first, but anyways it is resolved.

Comment: Glad to here that :) Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

It seems your checkbox was outside the form tag.
just replace your code with my code below:

```
//check for $_POST values
if((isset($_POST['submit']))&&(isset($_POST['todelete']))){
    $output_form= false;

    foreach($_POST['todelete'] as $delete_id){
       $query = "delete from email_list where id = $delete_id";
       mysqli_query($dbc,$query)or die('Error querying database.');
    }

    echo '<p>Customer entry removed</p>'.'<br />';
}elseif((isset($_POST['submit']))&&(empty($_POST['todelete']))){
    echo "<p>you haven't selected any customer entry to delete!</p>";
    $output_form= true;
}else {
    $output_form= true; 
}
//check if to show form
if($output_form){ ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <?php 
            $dbc= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customer_base')or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
            $query = "select * from email_list";
            $result= mysqli_query($dbc, $query)or die('Error querying database.');

            while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' .$row['id']. '"name="todelete[]" />';
               echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'].' '.$row['email'].' '.'<br />';
            }

            mysqli_close($dbc);
         ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="remove" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

as i can see you're using mysqli, i recommend you move on to PDO.